# How can I find the real bug in my files?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I wrote a program and want to debug it using firebug. But firebug always tells me there is something wrong with my library files such as jquery, which is absolutely not the root of the problem. It shows as follows:

```
((f.event.special[s.origType] || {}).handle || s.handler).apply is not a function

...{href:function(a){return a.getAttribute("href")},type:function(a){return a.getAt...     jquery....min.js (line 3)
```

I know there must be something wrong with my program. But how could I find the real bug in my files?

Comment: The debugger is going to catch where the error *actually* occurs, which may be deep inside of a library, although the "bug" started at your application code.  Do you have "show stack trace with errors" option enabled?

Comment: @mellamokb Yes, I have enabled the "show stack trace with errors" option. But I still have no clue when I expand the error message. And actually some of the error messages is just a single one and could not be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Place a breakpoint on the jQuery line where the error occurs and unwind the call stack until it originates with your code (which will probably call a jQuery method with incorrect argument types, etc).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*From @alex answer, here is how to use breakpoint.*

Click at line number that you want. Just keep an eye on the line and *press F10* to the next line. At line 10 will throw to library. Because an error. *Hope it can help you.*

Comment: But where should I put the breakpoint? I mean I don't know where the error originally comes from. Or should I put the breakpoint in the library file where the firebug find an error?

Comment: Okay.If it was me I would put it on the main code. I mean at the start point of javascript(not in library) and press F10 to find which line that have bug.